# My NTFS internal HDD is now detected RAW

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, backup, ntfs

This is my Crystal Disk Info snapshot:
[image: This is my Crystal Disk Info snapshot]

First of all, my machine is Windows 8.1 x64 with Media Center.
I noticed that my internal D: drive that was used to record TV recordings failed the other day. I checked the HDD which was NTFS is now recognized as RAW. The HDD is supposed to be 2TB, but CrystalDiskInfo and DiskManagement shows that it is only 1TB. I could not fix with ChkDsk, because it says that it cannot run on RAW.

So, let me limit the questions to:

1. How can I recover/ backup my files? I am interested to recover multimedia files, especially .wtv files.
2. How should I treat this HDD from now on? (Is this fixable by reformat? Or should I fix with special program? Is this HDD dying, therefore best to abandon?)
3. Any other suggestions to fix the issue?

I searched for clues that TestDiskInfo could give me something, but is this the right thing to me?

If this is duplicate, please point me to the answer, and let me know if the answer is still valid.

Comment: Your drive is starting to fail based on the bad sectors and the read errors it has encountered.

Comment: Any suggestion to fix the HDD? Are the files unrecoverable? I am looking for hope

Comment: There might be things you can do to recover the data, I have no specific suggestions, but there is no "fixing" the drive.  Physical sectors on the surface of the drive are indicated by the firmware information as being bad.  It appears that every sector that is being reallocated, generated an read error, that isn't good news for the infomrationon those sectors.

Comment: Before spending tons of money on a data recovery company, check out my answer on AU: http://askubuntu.com/a/776317/271 If it works for you I might consider writing a summary here.

Comment: thanks, my drive is mounted ok and diskmanagement shows 1TB only out of 2TB, so I think any software solution won't help me much. Since the damage is physical, I am currently trying to freeze my HDD and hope if it can be detected normally and do some recovery(file copying) as much as possible, starting from the important files. Hopefully it goes ok. Summer heat might have contributed the failure to my HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that, but the S.M.A.R.T. values are indicating that the HDD is about to fail.

Reallocated Sector Count are basically invisible bad sectors that have been swapped with reserve sectors. These sectors are no longer visible to your operating system and as such can never cause any more problems.

On the other hand, Current Pending Sectors Count are active visible bad sectors that cannot be read but are still visible to the operating system. When the drive detects an error during a write operation it can immediately remap to a sector reserved for this purpose. No data is lost. But if the error occurs during a read operation the drive cannot remap the sector because it doesn't know what the data is supposed to be. The drive makes a not of these and will remap them when or if the sector is later written to or if it can be successfully read. The "Pending Sector Count" is the count of these pending sectors.

As for the data, it will be best to contact a data recovery company and see if they'll be able to help you in this situation because the more you try to access the information, worse the damage and the extraction of files may become.

If you want you can take a look at the list of WD data recovery partners:

http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=UWVvSF